# TableLayout with different columns at different rows

Tags: android

I try to create a TableLayout with multi rows, and each row is having different columns

The following show list view. For each row of list view, it contains a table layout with only 1 row, 2 columns.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="6dip">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/color_label"
        android:layout_width="12dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:background="#ffffff" />

    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="1">
        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toptext"
                android:gravity="left"
            />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bottomtext"
                android:gravity="right"
            />       
        </TableRow>        

        <View android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:background="#FF909090" />
    </TableLayout>   
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the outcome.

[image]

Later, I want to further improve the TableLayout. With its 1st row is having 2 columns. and its 2nd row is having 4 columns, with a vertical line separates 1,2 columns with 3,4 columns.

I use the following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="6dip">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/color_label"
        android:layout_width="12dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:background="#ffffff" />

    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="1">
        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toptext"
                android:gravity="left"
            />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bottomtext"
                android:gravity="right"
            />       
        </TableRow>        

        <View android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:background="#FF909090" />

        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/col1"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="Column 1"
            />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/col2"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="Column 2"
            />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/col3"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="Column 3"
            />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/col4"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="Column 4"
            />            
        </TableRow>        


        <View android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:background="#FF909090" />

    </TableLayout>   
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the outcome.

[image]

However, the 2nd row of table layout is not something I want. What I wish to have is something like this.

[image]

How can I improve my XML to achieve the above effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own drawable xmls (inside `res/drawable-[h|m|l]dpi`) for the different item renderers, and set them as background.

This way you can achieve any kind of borders, shapes, etc., and in your `adapter`'s `getView` method you just inflate the view you need with the proper `backgroundDrawable`.

Comment: I also have the same requirement But if I have separate XML and I have scroll the The table horizontal then It not moves properly. What I have done header are declared in one XML and rows are declared in one XML and that XML I am inflating in the activity But what happening now their are two vies so what happening when I move bottom view which is list view the above view means column is not moving. and We cannot put listview inside the scroll view.